# Perform a event certain so many times every so many seconds

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a c# project where I need to perform a task so many times every so many seconds.

For example, write to the console 5 times every 1 second. How could I go about doing this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with? What do you not know how to do?

Comment: Loops and timers are your best friends here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
While (true)
{
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
 console ("Hello");
}
//this will pause for 1 sec (1000msec)
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: This isn't good if you're working on a user interface thread, because it will lock up. Also, if the OP wanted to do something else even when the 1/5th of a second task wasn't going, this would be impossible. A timer or time modulus check would be better.

Comment: Even on a non-UI thread it shouldn't be done in production, and it doesn't work very reliably as a timer anyway.  [More info here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Timer` and bind and event to the `Timer.Elapsed` event.

```
using System.Timers;
```

Sample code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(i);            
    }
};
```

Is this an console application, or do you run this on another thread?

Comment: Your example code doesn't have an interval set, and writes five times in an immediate row when it fires, not five times a second.

Comment: I interpreted the question as, write 5 times, each second. Of course, set the interval of the timer to an fifth of an second and write the line can be the solution in that case.

Comment: @dawmail333 Granted it's missing the interval and the call to start, but the OP clearly states write 5 times every x.

Answer (score 2):

For short stuff like this, use a timer. There are two main ones to choose from:

[System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

And:

[System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

The former uses the `ThreadPool`, the latter uses UI events. They both expose the ability to specify and interval and either a callback method or event to attach to in order to put custom code.

For longer periods of inactivity, look into scheduling either with the Windows scheduler (the OS one) or a scheduling framework such as [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Do note that the accuracy of the timers vary, but not really within margins that humans can detect :-)

Also note that the callback of the threaded timer will return on an arbitrary `ThreadPool` thread, so you could effectively end up "multi-threading" the code without realising it.

There is also System.Timers.Timer, it exposes an event. An article about the different timers available [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will affect you, but it's still worth knowing - windows is not a real-time OS; if you ask for something to be done every X milliseconds, it won't be exact, as for how much it will be out depends on a variety of things.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a thread to do it. Especially useful if you want to do a lot of processing! Here's an example of a thread doing work every 1s (1000ms):

```
public void Start()
{
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadFunction));
    thread.Start();
}

public virtual void ThreadFunction(object o)
{
    var insert = false;
    while (running)
    {
        //Do work
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```